# How to pass React click events to electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Just downloaded [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) and started to play around with the boilerplate but problems raised when I tried to create a chomeless transparent windows, so I created a little React TitleBar component, but I don't know how can I send the widnow minimize, maximize and close commands. I know that some sort of work must be done with the ipcRenderer but I can't even import that into my React component

As for testing, downloaded electron-react-boilerplate 4.4.0 and tried to import ipcRenderer in the React App component, this is the resulting code of my React component, and I'm attaching the error that I get in the console.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

import { MemoryRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import icon from '../../assets/icon.svg';
import './App.css';

class Hello extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(ipcRenderer);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Hello">
          <img width="200px" alt="icon" src={icon} />
        </div>
        <h1>electron-react-boilerplate</h1>
        <div className="Hello">
          <a
            href="https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <button type="button">
              <span role="img" aria-label="books">
                
              </span>
              Read our docs
            </button>
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://github.com/sponsors/electron-react-boilerplate"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <button type="button">
              <span role="img" aria-label="books">
                
              </span>
              Donate
            </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Hello} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/martinb/Escritorio/electron-react-boilerplate-4.4.0/node_modules/electron'
 @ ./src/renderer/App.tsx 10:19-38
 @ ./src/renderer/index.tsx 10:30-46

ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/martinb/Escritorio/electron-react-boilerplate-4.4.0/node_modules/electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./src/renderer/App.tsx 10:19-38
 @ ./src/renderer/index.tsx 10:30-46

webpack compiled with 2 errors
Not rewriting GET /index.html because the path includes a dot (.) character.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `window.electron.ipcRenderer` in react component

ipcRenderer should be required in `preload.js`, preload is a param of BrowserWindow webPreferences.

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });
```

please refer: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/main/src/main/main.ts

Comment: I guess, Why don't they just include that calls in the componentDidMount of the react App component... Thanks for the answer!